# Is there an alternative for the Tumblr Archive?

Tags: tumblr

I would like to present a more structured list of my posts on Tumblr.

Is there any way I can do this from within Tumblr itself?

Answer (score 1):

Tumblr offers the following ways to list posts automatically:

- There are the usual **pages**: `page/2`, `page/3`, …
- There are **tag** pages (where `foobar` is a tag):

  - newest first: `/tagged/foobar`, `/tagged/foobar/page/2`, …
  - oldest first: `` `/tagged/foobar/chrono ``, `/tagged/foobar/chrono/page/2`, …
- There are **date** pages: `/day/2013/09/27`, `/day/2013/09/28`, …
- There is the **archive**: `/archive`
- There are **sitemaps**: `/sitemap.xml` (resp. `/sitemap1.xml`, `/sitemap2.xml`, …)

With *Custom Pages* you could link and organize all your posts manually.

With the [API](http://www.tumblr.com/api) you could program a custom application.

Comment: mm. not what I meant. I just want to show my archive in a less fancy way, more dropdown-oldfashioned blogger like. I don't understand why this is still not possible.

Comment: @ThiemeHennis: Yes, I can imagine that none of these solutions satisfy you. But that is everything that Tumblr offers. For everything else, you’d need to build it yourself with the API or use a tool someone else built with the API.

Answer (score 1):

I've read of someone having success with adding their own Tumblr RSS to the sidebar, to get a chronological list of posts. With some CSS, you might be able to achieve what you want.

later: I believe this solution included the use of Feed2JS, by Adam Levine, 
http://cogdogblog.com/.

Is your archive huge? You could start building a Custom Page by hand - or did you want this to appear on the index page, like Blogger? There are so many themes out there now, many with the white space to add lists etc.

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: Google is your friend. Others have done this, so the CSS is out there. There may even be Tumblr support for this, by now.

Comment: I meant to say, your feed exists, your task would be to make those links match your theme, in nice lists. Drop-down, not sure. Got a sidebar?